# HTML <select> multiple with look and feel of single select

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

So, I have this weird requirement, where I have a `<select>` element with the `multiple` selection enabled.

```
<select multiple>
...
</select>
```

but due to the `multiple` attribute I shown the list of `option` with a scroll, which is not that is required.
We want to make it look like it was without the `multiple` attribute. I tried following but not sure if this is the right way:

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqd0yd5m/54/) for that and it does not look good.

```js
$("select").on("focus", function() {
  $("select").css({
    height: "100px",
    "overflow-y": "scroll"
  });
});

$("select").on("blur", function() {
  $("select").css({
    height: "18px",
    "overflow-y": "hidden"
  });
});
```

```css
select.drop-down-view {
  height: 18px;
  min-width: 54px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

select.drop-down-view:before {
  content: "Select";
}

select.drop-down-view:after {
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple class="drop-down-view">
  <option>123</option>
  <option>456</option>
  <option>789</option>
</select>
```

Can someone please suggest some better approach for this.
Thanks.

Comment: So you want to select multiple answers in the select dropdown?

Comment: Yes, but I can only try to change the look and feel of it and not the functionality

Comment: what if you insert checkboxes in front of the answers?

Comment: Checkboxes are not in options

Comment: Inside the dropdown, answers you can have check boxes to select multiple answers at once. something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbeh2.png

Comment: Checkboxes are out of scope, as I have to read values from checkboxes, which is kind of changing the functionality of the select, which is not in my hand

Comment: do you have to use `<select>` element?

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to achieve in a good way I believe. A "normal" `<select>` element displays the selected value when the element is blurred. How is that supposed to work in this case, when there can be multiple selected values?

With that said, I think you're actually on to something and tried fiddling around with your fiddle a bit.

I added a wrapper around the select element with the same height as the select, and then set the select to `position: absolute;` when it is expanded. This keeps the content below the select from being pushed down. I demonstrated this by adding some text displaying the selected values below the select.

When the select is blurred, it is scrolled to the top, where the default "Select" label is (at least in Chrome). Not very nice, but I think it looks better than having the label land between two of the actual values when the select is blurred.

See the forked fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ncevcw5p/3/